# How std::unordered_map Behaves? [C++]

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, std, unordered-map

I was reading about C++ unordered_map and have a few questions which I can't answer clearly.

I have noticed that unordered_map puts one element per index and not multiple (hash tables can be implemented using one of these methods to solve 2 elements being mapped to the same index)

1. If an element with key A in the map, and I insert another one it will override the previous element right? (no matter if the values match or not).
2. Is there an option to change the behavior of unordered_map so it can contain multiple elements per index like I explained above?
3. I have noticed from my code that unordered_map gets bigger by one every time I insert a new element but that's really bad, I learned in a hash table we need to multiply the size by 2 every time it's needed so complexity for inserting is O(1) Amortized and not O(n).
4. How can I give my unordered_map an initial size but with no elements? ie I know it will reach size 1000 so instead of making it bigger multiple times and doing heavy copying we can do it straight.

Comment: 2: Check std::multimap. 3. Are you confusing bucket count with element count? 4. Did you check the documentation? The `reserve` member function does that.

Comment: @Passerby for 3 I used size, how can I know the number of each one of those you mentioned?

Comment: Everything you need is at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map. For your first question you can look up `insert`. For your third you can look at `bucket_count`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me shortly answer your questions

1. No, you cannot insert a new key. The function will fail. Keys must be unique.
2. No, there is no option. If you want to store multiple same keys, the you need to use a `std::unordered_multimap` instead
3. You mix up bucket with number elements. Of course the mapwill grow, if you enter a new key. If there would be the same hash value for 2 different keys, then those would be stored in a bucket for the hash value.
4. This does not make that much sense. See 3. And, also logically: A map contains keys. And if a key is in, then you cannot overwrite. However, you may use its `reserve` function, to allocate internal space . . .

All this is explained in the CPP Reference. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)